# Can my employer surveil me while using "remote desktop"?

Tags: privacy, surveillance

My job uses the remote desktop application for us to work at home. I am just realizing that my laptop, and everything on it, can be opened through the file explorer on the remote desktop application. I am wondering if my emp

Comment: are you aware that you can choose what you share with the remote device?

Comment: The short answer is that remote desktop allows you to share a folder, or an entire drive from your local machine to your remote machine.  You might possibly be sharing your entire drive, which I wouldn't advise.  You can also disable the feature entirely, but in general it's a useful feature to send data back/forth.

Answer (score 1):

No, they cannot "surveil" you unless they are also using the connection and connect back to your machine. This is unlikely, and you would notice it unless you kept the connection up and they someone hijacked your RDP session.

In the RDP connection settings, you can determine what you share from your local machine in the "Local Resources" and "More..." section.

Answer (score 0):

The question you ask is difficult to be answered.

If we are talking about possibilities the answer would be "Yes" but if we are talking about feasibility, then it would be hard to say "Yes" because of many factors such as privacy rights, cost of surveillance, tools to do it, etc.

If you need to find out if they surveil you, you need to answer this question: "why should they do it? is it worth it to spend time and money to do it?". If the answer is yes, then you can go further and see what are the countermeasures or detection methods.

I would not scare you. The surveillance is unlikely to be happened by your employer unless they have your explicit consent. If you want to be sure, you need to sure about the resources you share, how you do the remote connection, etc.

The simplest way to detect (any maybe prevent) surveillance is using firewalls and anti-malware tools. They can be a help to detect anomalies in your network.